# Inconsistent data while using nestjs and typeorm

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a many-to-many relationship between Users and Positions. When I try to retrieve Users' data, each user has multiple associated positions. There are a total of 100 Users. However, when I apply a limit, for example, limit=10, I only get 8 User records, but the total number of associated positions is 20. These are the snippets of the models:

user.entity.ts

```
@ManyToMany(() => Position, (position) => position.users)
@Field(() => [Position], { nullable: true })
@JoinTable({
  name: 'pivot_user_position',
  joinColumn: { name: 'user_nip', referencedColumnName: 'nip' },
  inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'position_id' },
})
public positions?: Position[]

@OneToMany(() => PivotUserPosition, (user) => user.pivot)
@Field(() => [PivotUserPosition], { nullable: true })
public pivot?: PivotUserPosition[]
```

position.entity.ts

```
@ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.positions)
@JoinTable({
  name: 'pivot_user_position',
  joinColumn: { name: 'position_id' },
  inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'user_nip', referencedColumnName: 'nip' },
})
public users?: User[]
```

pivot-user-positions.entity.ts

```
@ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.positions, { eager: false })
@JoinColumn({ name: 'user_nip', referencedColumnName: 'nip' })
public user: User

@ManyToOne(() => Position, (position) => position.users)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'position_id' })
public position: Position

@ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.pivot)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'user_nip', referencedColumnName: 'nip' })
public pivot?: User
```

And here is the typeorm query.

```
  async getUsers(
    session: SessionPayload,
  ) {
    const query = this.user
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('user.positions', 'pos')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('pos.organization', 'org')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('pos.department_org', 'dorg')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.pivot', 'piv')
      .orderBy({ 'user.id': 'ASC' }).limit(10)
    return query.getMany()
  }
```

Here is the result.

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "Bey",
            "pivot": [
              {
                "position_id": "10000"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "Errico",
            "pivot": [
              {
                "position_id": "999991"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "Eni",
            "pivot": [
              {
                "position_id": "10001"
              },
              {
                "position_id": "13454"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "Budi",
            "pivot": [
              {
                "position_id": "10001"
              },
              {
                "position_id": "10042"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "Dedi",
            "pivot": [
              {
                "position_id": "10002"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "Usep",
            "pivot": [
              {
                "position_id": "100039927"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "Joe",
            "pivot": [
              {
                "position_id": "100039925"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "Moto",
            "pivot": [
              {
                "position_id": "100040057"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The expected result is to have 10 nodes as the limit; however, it only returns 8 nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this works like this, is because you're apply `LIMIT 10` after the left joins are made. if you count number of pivot records in the result, you will see exactly 10.

Possible solution here is to use two queries:

Firs query to get id's for the users that match query conditions with applied `limit`:

```js
    const userIds = await this.user
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .select('user.id')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('user.positions', 'pos')
      .orderBy({ 'user.id': 'ASC' })
      .limit(10)
      .getRawMany();
```

Second query to get users with joined properties:

```js
return this.user
  .createQueryBuilder('user')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('user.positions', 'pos')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('pos.organization', 'org')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('pos.department_org', 'dorg')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('user.pivot', 'piv')
  .where('user.id IN (:...ids)', { ids: userIds.map(u => u.id) })
  .orderBy({ 'user.id': 'ASC' })
  .getMany();
```